# JSF Richfaces 4.0 with MAVEN

Tags: jsf, maven, richfaces

I used the following script to create a jsf+richfaces project

```
 mvn archetype:generate \
       -DarchetypeGroupId=org.richfaces.archetypes \
       -DarchetypeArtifactId=richfaces-archetype-simpleapp \
       -DarchetypeVersion=4.0.0.Final \
       -DgroupId=com.confiz \
       -DartifactId=coinfling \
       -Dversion=1
```

This creates a sample jsf+richfaces project. I then use mvn eclipse:eclipse to create an eclipse project. When i import the project into eclipse, its gives a classpath error that all of my richfaces jar file are missing? I thought maven would download the jar files and places them into my project. This is the generated class path file from the mvn eclipse:eclipse phase

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/el/el-api/1.0/el-api-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/richfaces/ui/richfaces-components-ui/4.0.0.Final/richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/richfaces/ui/richfaces-components-api/4.0.0.Final/richfaces-components-api-4.0.0.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/richfaces/core/richfaces-core-api/4.0.0.Final/richfaces-core-api-4.0.0.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/google/guava/guava/r08/guava-r08.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/richfaces/core/richfaces-core-impl/4.0.0.Final/richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sourceforge/cssparser/cssparser/0.9.5/cssparser-0.9.5.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/w3c/css/sac/1.3/sac-1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.0.4-b09/jsf-api-2.0.4-b09.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.0.4-b09/jsf-impl-2.0.4-b09.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/1.6.0/ehcache-1.6.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/testng/testng/5.10/testng-5.10-jdk15.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

what am i doing wrong ? What is this M2 repo path ? What should i do now ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Do you have m2eclipse plugin installed in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to configure your workspace to add the M2_REPO to classpath as per
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/

"eclipse:configure-workspace is used to add the classpath variable M2_REPO to Eclipse which points to your local repository and optional to configure other workspace features."

Can you have a look whether the below link helps you :
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-convert-maven-java-project-to-support-eclipse-ide/

The other option is install the m2eclipse plugin.  Import your project as Maven existing project. I think things should work out without even running mvn eclipse:eclipse.
Since you have already run it, you can remove the classpath file and continue to import the project as maven existing project.  This should also generate the classpath file.

Here's something which gives differences between each :
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Eclipse+Integration

Hope it helps..